# Return a ReadOnlyDictionary sorted by value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I've got a method that contains a `Dictionary<string, uint>`. The method returns a `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint>` that is created from the `Dictionary<string, uint>`.

I wish to have the returned dictionary sorted by *value* and not by key. I have searched the internet and found some LINQ that sorts by value:

```
var sorted = from entry in _wordDictionary orderby entry.Value descending select entry;
```

However, I don't know how to then use this in conjunction with the `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint>` that I'm returning.

Here's my code:

```
public static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint> GetWordCountDictionary(string stringToCount)
{
    Dictionary<string, uint> wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

    //Rest of the method here that is not relevant

    var sorted = from entry in wordDictionary orderby entry.Value descending select entry;

    ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint> result = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint>(wordDictionary);

    return result;
}
```

As the code currently stands, this returns the unsorted dictionary, however, if I instead do:

```
ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint> result = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint>(sorted);
```

I get the errors:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary<string,uint>.ReadOnlyDictionary(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,uint>)' has some invalid arguments

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,uint>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,uint>'
```

How do I return the sorted by value dictionary?

**EDIT**

If it is relevant, this is how I am currently able to iterate over the results:

```
var result = WordCounter.GetWordCountDictionary(myString);

foreach (var word in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1}", word.Key, word.Value);
}
```

Comment: when you are debugging, what type is sorted?

Comment: Well so far the `sorted` query is the result of sorting wordDictionary

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to sort a readonlydictionary (normal dictionaries don't guarantee order while iterating over it). You could most likely return a readonly list of key-value pairs.

Comment: Side Note: dictionary doesn't guarantee the order of elements. So, sorting a dictionary by value(or by key) doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I see. So in my case I'm counting words, how else should I be able to find say the top five most common words in the dictionary?

Comment: Sort and return a List or an array. `dict.OrderBy(....).Take(5)`

Comment: A list of KeyValuePairs do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is expecting a `IDictionary<string,uint>` but you are giving it `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,uint>>`

```
var result = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint>(sorted.ToDictionary(x => x.Key,x => x.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are putting the sorted results into a dictionary, the order in which the items are returned during enumeration is undetermined, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

I suggest that you return the results in a list instead:

```
        var sorted = (from entry in wordDictionary
                     orderby entry.Value descending
                     select entry).ToList();

        foreach (var word in sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", word.Key, word.Value);
        }
```

The [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will result in a `System.Collections.Generic.List<KeyValuePair<string, uint>>`

Answer (score 0):

The fix for your issue is to change the line,

```
ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint> result = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint>(sorted);
```

to

```
ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint> result = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, uint>(sorted.ToDictionary(t => t.Key,t => t.Value));
```